# Multiply values of a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two dictionaries, for example:

```
{"1":2,2:"5",3:"abcd",5:7}

{"1":10,2:5,3:"123",5:2.5}
```

And I need to create a new dictionary, where the keys are the same as in the first two, but the value is a product of values corresponding to the key if both values are numbers, the sum of values if they are strings. Otherwise exclude the key (and value) from the answer.

So the answer there will be:
`{"1":20,3:"abcd123",5:17.5}`

Now my part of this code looks like this:

```py
total = {key: price * key_values[key] for key, price in key_values.items()}
```

Is it somewhere near?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt is is somewhat neat but (1) doesn't handle the types and (2) doesn't filter. I wouldn't use a dict comprehension here because filtering may be somewhat inconvenient. Just write this imperatively:

```py
dict_a = {"1":2,2:"5",3:"abcd",5:7}
dict_b = {"1":10,2:5,3:"123",5:2.5}

dict_merged = {}
for key, value_a in dict_a.items():
    value_b = dict_b[key]
    if type(value_a) == str and type(value_b) == str:
        dict_merged[key] = value_a + value_b
    elif type(value_a) in (int, float) and type(value_b) in (int, float):
        dict_merged[key] = value_a * value_b
```

Comment: If key is not in dict_b you get a key error

Comment: @Jako the OP shows two dicts with same keys so I assumed that was a given. Otherwise just add `if key not in dict_b: continue`.

Comment: elif incorrect i.e. has `type(value_a)` twice.  Second should be `type(value_b)``.

Answer (score 1):

Not recommended to use a dictionary comprehension if you are going to have conditions in there.

```
a = {"1":2,2:"5",3:"abcd",5:7}
b = {"1":10,2:5,3:"123",5:2.5}
c = {}
for key,value in a.items():
    b_value = b[key]
    if all(isinstance(x, (int, float)) for x in [value, b_value]):
        c[key] = value * b_value
    elif all(isinstance(x, str) for x in [value, b_value]):
        c[key] = value + b_value

print(c)
```

Ouptut:

```
{'1': 20, 3: 'abcd123', 5: 17.5}
```

Note: This is assuming that pre-condition you mentioned of both dicts to have same keys always is always met

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use dict comprehensions, then do something like this:

```
d1= {"1":2,2:"5",3:"abcd",5:7}
d2= {"1":10,2:5,3:"123",5:2.5}

# filter out keys that aren't shared, and if they are shared, then make sure they have a value of the same type
d3 = {key:0 for key in set(d1.keys()).intersection(set(d2.keys())) if type(d1[key])== type(d2[key])}

# Combine the values of all the keys that remain 
d4 = { key:d1[key]+d2[key] if type(d1[key]) == str else d1[key]+d2[key]  for key in d3 }
```

Or if you want you can nest them to put it all in one line, but its not so readable:

```
d4 = { key:d1[key]+d2[key] if type(d1[key]) == str else d1[key]+d2[key]  for key in {key:0 for key in set(d1.keys()).intersection(set(d2.keys())) if type(d1[key])== type(d2[key])} }
```

But these options are less efficient than the traditional for loops other people have suggested to use, which is what I would suggest using.