# How to multiply two values from two dictionaries to return a total

Tags: python

here is my code:

#A list containing 4 menu items
Menu = ["Coffee","Latte","Tea","Capuccino"]

#A dictionary containing stock values for each menu item
Stock = {"Coffee":"50",
"Latte":"150",
"Tea":"100",
"Capuccino":"200"
}

#A dictionary containing prices for each menu item
Price = {"Coffee":"22",
"Latte":"27",
"Tea":"17",
"Capuccino":"32"
}

Stock_values = Stock.values()
for x in Stock_values:
print(int(x))

Price_values = Price.values()
for y in Price_values:
print(int(y))

stock_worth = x*y

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72423841/multiply-values-of-a-dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

```
stock_worth = {key: int(Stock[key]) * int(Price[key]) for key in Stock.keys()}

print(stock_worth)
>>> {'Coffee': 1100, 'Latte': 4050, 'Tea': 1700, 'Capuccino': 6400}
```

Without using dictionary comprehension, it would be

```
value = {}
for key in Stock.keys():
    value[key] = int(Stock[key]) * int(Price[key])
print(value)
>>> {'Coffee': 1100, 'Latte': 4050, 'Tea': 1700, 'Capuccino': 6400}
```

Comment: It says the name key is not defined

Comment: Which version of python do you have? Did you try both versions of my code? They work for me, using the two dictionaries you defined in your description. And I'm sure `key` doesn't need to be defined _a priori_.